# Open source libraries for metrics and dashboards to display them

Tags: software-development, monitoring, system-monitor

Say I write a C++/Python application and I want to monitor things like batch processing time, etc. Are there open source libraries that I can integrate into my application? I want to be able to consume these metrics and display them on a webpage/etc. I would be running this on a UNIX machine and would like to be able to go to a page via localhost and see the metrics evolve over time.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there are gratis open source software for both real-time and batch plotting of code metrics. They are:

- [Graphite](https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html)

  About Graphite:

> Graphite does two things:
>
> - Store numeric time-series data
> - Render graphs of this data on demand
>
> What Graphite does not do is collect data for you, however there are
> some tools out there that know how to send data to graphite. Even
> though it often requires a little code, sending data to Graphite is
> very simple.

- [Redash](http://redash.io/)

About Redash:

> re:dash was built to allow fast and easy access to billions of
> records, that we process and collect using Amazon Redshift (“petabyte
> scale data warehouse” that “speaks” PostgreSQL). Today *re:dash* has
> support for querying multiple databases, including: Redshift, Google
> BigQuery,Google Spreadsheets, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Graphite and custom
> scripts.

In fact, you can display the metrics and dashboards using D3 + (any python MVC framework like Django, Flask, etc)